# How do i update different table from the same access database using visual basic .net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I added my Enrollment system access Database, into my Enrollment System vb.net form, as a data source. The Database has 2 tables in it, the accountTable and studentEnrollmentInformation. I dragged The accountTable's details and data grid view into my form designer. The following code automatically appeared in the code designer:

```
Private Sub AccountTableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Me.Validate()
    Me.AccountTableBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.EnrollmentSystemDataBaseDataSet)
End Sub



Private Sub enrollmentSystem_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     Me.AccountTableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.EnrollmentSystemDataBaseDataSet.accountTable)     
End Sub
```

The following code works for updating the accounTableDataGridView but it does not work for studentEnrollmentInformationDataGridView so i manually created one
for studentEnrollmentInformation.

```
Function updateStudent()
        Me.Validate()
        Me.StudentEnrollmentInformationBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.EnrollmentSystemDataBaseDataSet)
       Me.StudentEnrollmentInformationTableAdapter.Fill(Me.EnrollmentSystemDataBaseDataSet.studentEnrollmentInformation)
End Function
```

This is the function that contains the update code, that i manually created for updating the studentEnrollmentDataGridView. Adding new Row works fine but when i try to update studentEnrollmentDataGridView the texts in the table disappears and does not update/save. I also had function for updating the accountTableDataGridView which works fine.

```
Function update() 'THIS FUNCTION CONTAINS PRE-MADE CODE TO MAKE UPDATING SHORTER IN WRITING CODE.
    Me.Validate()
    Me.AccountTableBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.EnrollmentSystemDataBaseDataSet)
    Me.AccountTableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.EnrollmentSystemDataBaseDataSet.accountTable)
End Function
```

My Question is how do i update multiple Tables in my system? Updating the other table works fine but the other is not.

Answer (score 0):

In the original auto-generated code, this is the line that retrieves the data in the first place:

```
Private Sub enrollmentSystem_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     Me.AccountTableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.EnrollmentSystemDataBaseDataSet.accountTable)     
End Sub
```

When the form loads, the Account data is retrieved into a `DataTable` that is already bound.  If you want to retrieve Student Enrollment data too, do it in the same place:

```
Private Sub enrollmentSystem_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     Me.AccountTableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.EnrollmentSystemDataBaseDataSet.accountTable)
     Me.StudentEnrollmentInformationTableAdapter.Fill(Me.EnrollmentSystemDataBaseDataSet.studentEnrollmentInformation)
End Sub
```

Now you're populating both bound `DataTables` when the form loads.  When it comes to saving, you do the same thing, i.e. add the code to save the changes to the other `DataTable` where you already have the code to save the first:

```
Private Sub AccountTableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Me.Validate()
    Me.AccountTableBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.StudentEnrollmentInformationBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.EnrollmentSystemDataBaseDataSet)
End Sub
```

You don't need any code to specifically save the changes from the `DataTable` because the whole point of `UpdateAll` is that it updates all `DataTables` in the `DataSet`.

As is always the case, if it doesn't seem to be working as you expect then you debug it.  In that case, that would mean setting a breakpoint on the `UpdateAll` line and examining the exact state of the `DataSet` before and after the call, as well as possibly examing the sate of the database too.

Comment: Than you Mr. but unfortunately it does not work. What do you think is the reason why is it not working? and what should be my approach to this problem so that i could solve it?

Comment: You should debug the code, as I said. To say that something is not working is not sufficient explanation of a problem. You need to provide specifics of the symptoms for us to diagnose the issue.